# win32-api insallation issue on linux

Tags: ruby, linux, ruby-on-rails-3, winapi, ubuntu

I am ubuntu guy and not able to install win32-api.

## Please find my log

Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing win32-api:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

```
    /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby extconf.rb
```

checking for strncpy_s()... no
creating Makefile

make
gcc -I. -I/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/include/ruby-1.9.1/i686-linux -I/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/include/ruby-1.9.1 -Iwin32 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -fPIC -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-long-long  -fPIC  -o api.o -c win32/api.c
win32/api.c:2:21: error: windows.h: No such file or directory
win32/api.c:33: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘HANDLE’
win32/api.c: In function ‘api_free’:
win32/api.c:40: error: ‘Win32API’ has no member named ‘library’
win32/api.c:41: error: ‘Win32API’ has no member named ‘library’
win32/api.c: At top level:
win32/api.c:58: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘dwError’
win32/api.c: In function ‘callback_init’:
win32/api.c:189: error: ‘LPARAM’ undeclared (first use in this function)
win32/api.c:189: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
win32/api.c:189: error: for each function it appears in.)
win32/api.c:189: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘find_callback’
win32/api.c: In function ‘api_init’:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Win32 API only exists on Windows. Or in WINE, but going that route is more complex than you're ready for.

Comment: I am using watir. Is there any comparative of Win32 API, because I am getting error while I install watir

Comment: Uh, Watir doesn't require Windows, therefore you must be doing something horribly, horribly wrong.